# Unable to connect to any services via 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking, localhost

I logged into a 16.04 server we hadn't touched for months, did an `apt-get upgrade` and rebooted it.

Now unable to reach anything via `127.0.0.1`, e.g.

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 3308
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

However localhost works e.g.

```
$ telnet localhost 3308
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
_
$B9+/&0X???gbJ:< hDWfM5mysql_native_password
```

So IPv6 is working, but IPv4 apparently not. Problem is I have a bunch of services trying to connect via IPv4.

**Further information:**

No, this is not the same as the 16.04 upgrade issue, network access is not a problem.

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f2:3c:91:e2:e9:e3  
          inet addr:139.*.*.*  Bcast:139.*.*.*  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::*:*:*:*/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a01:*::*:*:*:*/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:420333 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:427976 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:103142955 (103.1 MB)  TX bytes:41541069 (41.5 MB)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f2:3c:91:e2:e9:e3  
          inet addr:192.168.*.*  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.128.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:46250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:46250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:48447261 (48.4 MB)  TX bytes:48447261 (48.4 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.5.4.1  P-t-P:10.5.4.1  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fbaa:a6ee:9adf:f417/64 Scope:Link
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7859 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5347 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:489368 (489.3 KB)  TX bytes:1483636 (1.4 MB)
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   hostname.my.domain  hostname
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Check `HerrTaschenbier` answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767574/no-network-after-upgrade-to-16-04) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No network after upgrade to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767574/no-network-after-upgrade-to-16-04)

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `cat /etc/hosts`... and you only need to copy/paste the first 4-5 lines... I don't need to see the whole file. Please don't put that output into comments. Start comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: What does `ifconfig lo` show?

Comment: @heynnema added

Comment: @psusi added too