# No network connection after update from 16.04 to 17.04

Tags: networking, wireless, updates, dhcp

Edit2: DHCP works now, thanks to this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/767944/533373

I still don't have wlan/wireless.

<del>Actually I have two problems, I'm not sure if I should make two posts.</del>

I updated Ubuntu from 16.04 to 17.04, after reboot I didn't have Internet access.

`ifconfig -a` shows my ethernet card (name changed from eth0 to enp0s31f6) but not my wlan.

When I execute `sudo dhclient enp0s31f6` in the console I get an IP-address and have internet.

So my questions:

<del>1. How can I get the system to automatically start dhcp and get an IP-address?</del>

2. Why doesn't my wlan show up and how do I get it to work again?

Edit:

```
ifconfig -a
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:36:af:c6:d8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.121  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::ca5b:76ff:fe81:a829  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c8:5b:76:81:a8:29  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 659199  bytes 146849388 (146.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 375507  bytes 56632882 (56.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xf1200000-f1220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
        RX packets 1096  bytes 128548 (128.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1096  bytes 128548 (128.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

This is after I manually executed `sudo dhclient enp0s31f6`, before there isn't an ip, also you can see wlan is missing.

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback



lshw -C network

  *-network UNGEFORDERT     
       Beschreibung: Network controller
       Produkt: Wireless 8260
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:03:00.0
       Version: 3a
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       Konfiguration: latency=0
       Ressourcen: memory:f1000000-f1001fff
  *-network
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 1f.6
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       Logischer Name: enp0s31f6
       Version: 21
       Seriennummer: c8:5b:76:81:a8:29
       Größe: 1Gbit/s
       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
       Breite: 32 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.12-3 ip=192.168.0.121 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       Ressourcen: irq:125 memory:f1200000-f121ffff
  *-network
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Physische ID: 2
       Logischer Name: docker0
       Seriennummer: 02:42:36:af:c6:d8
       Fähigkeiten: ethernet physical
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

Edit2: Seems to be a problem with the firmware, but that doesn't really help me :(

```
    Jan 15 11:53:57 pc643 kernel: [   17.954134] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode failed with error -2
    Jan 15 11:53:57 pc643 kernel: [   17.954148] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-32.ucode failed with error -2
    Jan 15 11:53:57 pc643 kernel: [   17.955094] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode failed with error -2
    Jan 15 11:53:57 pc643 kernel: [   17.955106] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-30.ucode failed with error -2
    Jan 15 11:53:57 pc643 kernel: [   17.955114] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-29.ucode failed with error -2
    Jan 15 11:53:57 pc643 kernel: [   17.956268] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-28.ucode failed with error -2
    Jan 15 11:53:57 pc643 kernel: [   17.956282] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode failed with error -2
    Jan 15 11:53:57 pc643 kernel: [   17.956289] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode failed with error -2
    Jan 15 11:53:57 pc643 kernel: [   17.956297] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode failed with error -2
    Jan 15 11:53:57 pc643 kernel: [   17.956311] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2
    Jan 15 11:53:57 pc643 kernel: [   17.956320] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2
    Jan 15 11:53:57 pc643 kernel: [   17.956328] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode failed with error -2
    Jan 15 11:53:57 pc643 kernel: [   17.956329] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
```

Comment: Please add the output of `ifconfig -a` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: @derHugo I added both. ifconfig is obviously after manually starting dhclient, or I couldn't post here :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got it:

Ethernet/DHCP problem was fixed with this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/767944/533373

Wireless/Wlan problem was fixed by downloading this git repo:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

And then copying all files to /lib/firmware.

I'm really disappointed in Ubuntu that I had to do all this by hand :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your network configuration got corrupted after the update. I don't have an expert solution, but this'll solve your problem! Follow these steps :

*1.) Create a .sh file containing this :*

```
echo <password> | sudo -S dhclient enp0s31f6
```

*2.) Execute this in terminal :*

```
chmod +x <path-to-your-script>/script.sh
```

*3.) Go to "Startup Applications", add a new startup item, browse to the script file and add it.*

[See this screenshot...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONcd9.jpg)

*4.) Done. This'll resolve your internet connection every time you log in!*

*-- I don't have solution for your first problem. Sorry for not being able to answer.*

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I found a better solution!

Comment: What was the better solution, @Fels?